# Traverse (2n+1)(2n+1) Array from centre out in diamond pattern?

Tags: python, arrays, list, traversal

1How would I traverse an array from the centre outwards, visiting each cell only once?

I can do it with a breadthfirst traversal by finding unvisited neighbours, but how could I do it with some kind of edit-distance traversal? I've been trying to figure it out on paper, but can't wrap my head around it.

eg, in an array

```
[
[5 6 8 9 0]
[1 2 4 5 6]
[5 4 0 2 1]
[1 2 3 4 5]
[1 2 3 4 5]]
```

starting from the zero in the centre, we would visit the 4 at `[1][2]` then the 2 at `[2][3]` then the 3 at `[3][2]` then the 4 at `[2][1]` then the 8 at `[0][2]`and then the 5 at the `[1][3]` etc etc

I've tried this, which gets close, but misses some.

```
def traversalOrder(n): #n is size of array (always square)

    n = n/2
    t = []
    for k in range(1,n+1):
        t += [(i,j) for i in range(n-k,n+k+1) for j in range(n-k,n+k+1) if (i,j) not in t and (i-j == k or j-i == k)  ]
```

Comment: What about 0 at [1][4]? That will never be visited?

Comment: I know. That's one of my problems. Like I said, my code misses some, and I need help to fix it :)

Comment: You havn't explained the order clearly. Can you please mention the complete expected output?

Comment: sure, I just want a list of tuples that contain the cell coordinates to visit. The order of tuples should be all cells in the first "ring" (there will be 4 cells in this ring), then all cells in the second ring (there will be 8 cells in this ring), then all cells in the third etc. The order of the first 4 cells doesn't matter, nor the next 8 cells, but they must be in "ring" order. 

Not sure if that makes more sense?

Answer (score 1):

I have an open source library [pixelscan](https://github.com/dpmcmlxxvi/pixelscan) that does this sort of spatial pattern traversal on a grid. The library provides various scan functions and coordinate transformations. For example,

```
x0, y0, r1, r2 = 0, 0, 0, 2
for x, y in ringscan(x0, y0, r1, r2, metric=manhattan):
    print x, y
```

where

```
x0     = Circle x center
y0     = Circle y center
r1     = Initial radius
r2     = Final radius
metric = Distance metric
```

produces the following points in a diamond:

```
(0,0) (0,1) (1,0) (0,-1) (-1,0) (0,2) (1,1) (2,0) (1,-1) (0,-2) (-1,-1) (-2,0) (-1,1)
```

You can apply a translation to start at any center point you want.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you could use some sort of priority queue to sort the elements based on an edit distance, like you suggested. While my edit distance doesn't give you the EXACT order you are looking for, it might be a starting point. I used [heapq](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html).

```
import heapq

grid = [
[5, 6, 8, 9, 0],
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6],
[5, 4, 0, 2, 1],
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

rows = len(grid)
cols = len(grid[0])

heap_list = []

for row in xrange(rows):
    for col in xrange(cols):
        edit_distance = abs(row - rows/2) + abs(col - cols/2)
        #heappush(heap, (priority, object))
        heapq.heappush(heap_list, (edit_distance, grid[row][col]))

for i in xrange(len(heap_list)):
    print heapq.heappop(heap_list)

# prints (distance, value)
# (0, 0)
# (1, 2)
# (1, 3)
# (1, 4)
# (1, 4)
# (2, 1)
# etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is with three nested loops. The outer most loop is over the expanding radiuses of your diamonds. The next loop is the four sides of a given diamond, described by a starting point and a vector the move along. The innermost loop is over the points along that side.

```
def traversal(n):
    h = n//2
    yield h, h   # center tile doesn't get handled the by the loops, so yield it first
    for r in range(1, n):
        for x0, y0, dx, dy in [(h, h-r, 1, 1),
                               (h+r, h, -1, 1),
                               (h, h+r, -1, -1),
                               (h-r, h, 1, -1)]:
            for i in range(r):
                x = x0 + dx*i
                y = y0 + dy*i
                if 0 <= x < n and 0 <= y < n:
                    yield x, y
```

If `n` is always odd, you can improve the performance of the inner loop a bit by limiting `i` rather than computing all the points and doing bounds tests to skip the ones that are outside your grid. Switching `range(r)` to `range(max(0, r-h), max(r, h+1))` and getting rid of the `if` before the `yield` should do it. I'll leave the version above however, since its logic is much more clear.