# How to get Manhattan cells' values around another cell by radius?

Tags: algorithm, lua, cell

I'm having some issues finding an algorithm to get the cells' values around a cell.

Here is a picture I modified explaining the situation :
[image: Cellules with their respective values]

I want to put in a table all the light blue values, that are around the dark blue cell in a radius of x (3 in the picture).

I tried to find some formulas on the Internet and also here but found nothing.

Comment: Not an answer but a key world related to these types of problems: [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics))

Comment: On YouTuble the channel [PBS Infinite Series](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCs4aHmggTfFrpkPcWSaBN9g/videos) has a video talking about this but I couldn't find the exact video.

Comment: Hello, thank your for your comment. As I said to @mahbubcseju , I don"t have the coordinates of the cell, I only have their respective numerical representation.

Comment: If you don't have the coordinates of the cell then how does the data represent the cells such that there is a location relation between two cells? I know that sounds confusing but it I need it to be unambiguous.

Comment: Okay, I just found the relation

_cellCoords.x = cellId % 14;
_cellCoords.y = Math.floor(cellId / 14);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local cell = 369
local r = 3
for x = -r, r do 
    for y = -r, r do 
        if math.abs(x) + math.abs(y) <= r then 
            local new_cell = cell + 29*math.floor(x/2) - 27*math.floor(y/2) + (x+y)%2 * (math.floor(cell/14)%2 + 14*(x%2-y%2)) + x*(x+y+1)%2
            print(new_cell)
        end 
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are at cell(x,y) , then all the cells (x1,y1) whose manhattan distance with cell (x,y) is less than or equal 3 are will be within radius 3

so if abs(x-x1)+abs(y-y1) less than or equal 3  then (x1,y1) will be within radius 3 of (x,y).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I don't have the x and y values of the cells, I just have their numeric values like shown in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32929320/3833603) is a link to similar question already answered. The answer I provided there is the same I would offer here.

I have a project [pixelscan](https://github.com/dpmcmlxxvi/pixelscan) that can traverse a grid in a variety of patterns, including a Manhattan ring pattern, and can be used to extract the cell values. It's in Python not Lua but the code is simple enough that is can be copy/pasted and tweaked to work.